# Difference between glMulMatrix and glTranslate (or glRotate)

Tags: opengl, rotation, translation

I'm used to modern OpenGL syntax, but I have to work on an existing code that uses the old syntax, which is so confusing for me despite the fact that it's supposed to be simpler!

I was wondering what's the difference between using `glMulMatrix` (and passing a translation matrix) and using `glTranslate` and passing `x`, `y`, and `z` for translation?

Same question applies for `glMulMatrix` (and passing a rotation matrix) or using `glRotate` and passing `x`, `y`, and `z` rotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `glMultMatrix`, you need to create the matrix (in column major order), by yourself, and pass it to OpenGL, using that function. By using `glTranslate` or `glRotate`, you only need to pass parameters and let OpenGL construct it.

After that, the processing will be the same. In the past, for beginners, using `glTranslate` or `glRotate` was easier to understand and use, while for more advanced user, `glMultMatrix` was more natural, due the fact that usually you accumulate transformations (scene graph) and pass it to compound scenes.

Comment: So, what would happen with this scenario: we have a `glTranslate` so that we render an object (e.g., a cube) in a specific location. Now, we want to rotate a specific vertex or even all the vertices (e.g., using mouse). We know that the correct order is 1. rotation, 2. translation, but if we were to apply `glRotate` now, it would be the other way. Am I right? If so, is there any way to rectify this?

Comment: @Farzad: You're on the right track of thinking. And the solution is either using `glPushMatrix` and `glPopMatrix` to save/restore depth levels in a transformation hierarchy and `glLoadIdendity` to "restart".

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more about those? When we do `glPushMatrix`, I'm assuming that it means that we're ignoring what we have as our matrix and start with a new matrix. Is this true? And if it's the case, what's the use of `glLoadIdentity`? Because in the code I'm dealing with right now, they do `glPushMatrix` and then do translation/rotation directly, without loading the identity matrix

Comment: @Farzad Imagine you want to model sun-earth-moon dynamics. You start reseting your matrix transformation (`glLoadIdentity`). To draw earth-moon, you translate and rotate this system as a whole (so, you apply glRotate and glTranslate). Now, you want to rotate moon around earth. So you will to do a `glPushMatrix` to save actual matrix, because you will need it when you start to draw earth. Now, you apply rotation and translate to moom, draw it, do a `glPopMatrix`, recovering the saved matrix, and draw earth.

Comment: So, when we do `plPushMatrix`, we don't need to do `glLoadIdentity`? Is it by default the identity matrix (with the coordinate system being the one we generated with previous `glRotate` and `glTranslate`) and we just apply everything we want? Am I right?

Comment: Kind of correct. Imagine it as a stack. When you do a `glPushMatrix` you just copy the top element and push it as a new top on this stack. When you do a `glPopMatrix` you just pop the top element (discarding it) and make the immediate below element as a new top. Maybe [this site](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html) could help. Just scroll down until you get a section entitled "Manipulating the Matrix Stacks"